# mplot3d: how to show the ticks but not the grids?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I want to show the axis ticks with matplotlib/mplot3d but not the faint grids on the x/y/z background:

[image]

Is there a way to suppress the grids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ax.grid(False)` should suffice. Self contained example, adding that line to [this](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.grid(False)
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()
```